# What is the vba regular expression for tab key?

Tags: vba

My string is `"  1.1"` which has one tab key at the front and I use the regular expression pattern `^\t` to find it.

But I failed. So what is the VBA regular expression for the tab key?

Comment: There is no VBA regular expressions. You have to use the syntax of whatever regex library you are using. E.g. `^\t` would be correct for [Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/11683).

Comment: Are you sure tab is your only problem? The dot, if unescaped, will cause you trouble as well

Answer (score 0):

The regex for this would be (specifically for 1.1) :

```
^[\t]1\.1
```

That said, it would be nice to see how you're implementing it in your VBA because, as GSerg says, VBA does not have native regex.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put a tab character before the `"1.1"` in your string you use `Char(9) & "1.1"`

If you want to find it, it may work. You would also like to try with vbTab